# Splitting PDF and Saving file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting an error in the code I am trying to write in windows forms, I am not sure what this code is doing as I am new to programming, I keep getting illegal characters error. The code section I am getting the error on is here:

```
string filename = "*.pdf";
File.Copy(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\ron.nogal\Desktop\test\new file\filename"),
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),filename),true);
```

Please help

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is collecting the data I want, Is this correct?

Comment: We have no idea what data you want.  You need to be more specific.

Comment: also on my winforms I have a textBox1 could I do something like                                      File.Copy(Path.Combine( and then include my textBox1 data

Comment: Yes Amy, I understand that, I am attempting to open a pdf document, split the pages and then save out as new files, my question is that code sample I posted above contains 2 lines of code, I googled it and cant figure out what the code does

Comment: `File.Copy`, if you had to venture a guess, what does that name suggest that function does?  Going a step further, the documentation for [`File.Copy` is on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)..  Can you find the documentation for `Path.Combine`?

Comment: @Amy Than you I think I may have tried to search the entire line rather than the File.Copy, I appreciate your assistance for the noob

Comment: Searching for entire lines of code is rarely helpful.  Break the code up into pieces and search for those instead.  Software is composed of pieces which can be combined in an unlimited number of ways.  You need to discover what those pieces are, then compose what they do in your head.  Rather than googling the entire thing to figure out what the entire thing does.  So in this case, figure out `File.Copy` and what it does, then `Path.Combine` and what it does.  Putting those together, you can understand the whole.

Comment: That makes since thank you, @Amy